# Caching values in ConcurrentHashmap to avoid database read

Tags: java, multithreading

Is my code below correct at using a Map as a simple ***threadsafe*** cache to avoid reading from the database? I just want to know the correctness of the code below rather than suggestions to use framework X instead.

```
public class Foo {
    private static final Map<String, String> CACHE = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void doWork(String key) {
        String value = CACHE.get(key);
        if (value == null) {
            synchronized (CACHE) {
                value = CACHE.get(key);
                if (value == null) {
                    value = database.getValue();
                    CACHE.put(key, value);
                }
            }
        }
        // do work with value
    }
}
```

Other Questions:

1. Instead of using `CACHE` in `synchronized()`, would it be better if I have a `Object lock` in my class and use synchronized on that instead?
2. Would using `HashMap` for `CACHE` instead work?

Comment: Actually you are asking for a code review ... not sure if this belongs here. Anyway: not sure what you mean with "Object lock" ... you see, you are actually **locking** on an object, in this case the cache. And for the second part, you have multiple threads accessing a hashmap; so why do you think that would work if you do **not** care about the multi-threading part?!

Comment: Best opportunity to learn about threads. Find out the answers yourself by trying some multithreaded unit tests. If you get stuck in the tests come back and ask for help.

Comment: You potentially may encounter starvation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/starvelive.html) as database access usually takes a long time. Specifically, think of many threads trying to fetch different keys when none of the keys is in the cache. Hint: Don't try to synchronize on String because strings are interned.

Comment: @Mrunal That's pretty much *the* worst possible advice you can give anyone when talking about threading. No, you don't learn anything about threading by trying and seeing what happens! You can't do learning by doing with concurrency. Anyhow the code is broken because you can read (get) and write (put) to the map at the same time which is not allowed  for that class (in practice you might e.g. get an infinite loop if a resize happens while reading).

Answer (score 4):

There is a fairly standard "pattern" for using `ConcurrentHashMap` in this way (in this case, you **do not** want to use a `synchronized` block or other locking mechanism):

```
        String value = CACHE.get(key);
        if (value == null) {
/* 3 */    String newValue = calculateValueForKey(key);
/* 4 */    value = CACHE.putIfAbsent(key, newValue);
           if (value == null) {
               value = newValue;
           }
        }

        /* Work with 'value' */
```

This approach works well when `calculateValueForKey()` runs quickly and doesn't have any side effects - it could be invoked multiple times for the same key depending on timing. The downside is that if `calculateValueForKey()` takes a long time and is I/O bound (as it is in your case) you could have multiple threads that are all running `calculateValueForKey()` for the same key at the same time. If there are 3 threads executing line 3 for the same key, 2 of them will "lose" at line 4 and have their results thrown away which is not very efficient. For these situations I would recommend something along these lines which is mostly lifted from the `Memoizer` example in [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) *(Goetz, B. (2006))* which I highly recommend:

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<String, Future<String>> CACHE
        = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void doWork(String key)
{
    String value;

    try {
        value = calculateValueForKey(key);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Restore interrupted status and return
        Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
        return;
    }

    // do work with value
}

private String calculateValueForKey(final String key)
         throws InterruptedException
{
    while (true) {
        Future<String> f = CACHE.get(key);
        if (f == null) {
            FutureTask<String> newCalc = new FutureTask<>(new Callable<String>() {
                @Override
                public String call()
                {
                    return database.getValue(key);
                }
            )};

            f = CACHE.putIfAbsent(key, newCalc);
            if (f == null) {
                f = newCalc;
                newCalc.run();
            }
        }

        try {
            return f.get();
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            CACHE.remove(key, f);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
                throw (RuntimeException) cause;
            } else if (cause instanceof Error) {
                throw (Error) cause;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Not unchecked", cause);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this code is more complex, which is why I've extracted the meat of it into another method, but it is very powerful. Rather than putting the value into the map, you are putting a `Future` that represents the *calculation* of that value into the map. Calling `get()` on that future will block until the computation is complete. This means that if 3 threads were simultaneously trying to retrieve the value for a given key, only a single computation would be run while all 3 threads waiting on the same result. Subsequent requests for the same key would return immediately with the calculated result.

To answer your specific questions:

1. ***Is my code below correct at using a Map as a simple threadsafe cache to avoid reading from the database?*** I'm going to say no. You're use of a `synchronized` block here is unnecessary. Furthermore if multiple threads are simultaneously trying to access the values for different keys that are not yet in the `Map`, they will block each other during their respective database queries, meaning that they will run in serial rather than in parallel.
2. ***Instead of using CACHE in `synchronized()`, would it be better if I have a Object lock in my class and use synchronized on that instead?*** No. You would typically use a surrogate object for synchronization when you want to read/write multiple mutable fields and you don't want consumers of your class to be able to affect the synchronization semantics of your object "from the outside."
3. ***Would using `HashMap` for `CACHE` instead work?*** I guess you could? But then you would need to adjust your synchronization policies so that `CACHE` (or a surrogate lock object) is always `synchronized` when the `Map` is read from or written to. I'm not sure why you would want to do that given better alternatives.

Comment: Appreciate your insightful response. You mentioned "it could be invoked multiple times for the same key depending on timing". Could you point out how? Since each thread can only enter into the `synchronized` block one at a time, and there's an additional check for the value in the map, how could it happen?

Comment: I was speaking about the hypothetical method `calculateValueForKey()` being called from the first example I provided. There is no synchronization there (and that's the point). As I mentioned, the major shortcoming of your implementation is that threads fetching values for _different_ keys will run serially.

Comment: For your response to question 1 "You're use of a synchronized block here is unnecessary", isn't the synchronized block necessary though if I want to prevent the same key from being computed multiple times? Granted, it would like you say, block on different keys.

Comment: Also, If the calculateValueForKey() *was* intensive, would you suggest adding a synchronized block in your code (similar to mine) to prevent multiple invocations of calculateValueForKey()?

Comment: If `calculateValueForKey()` is expensive, I would use the Memoizer example that I included in my answer. It results in at most 1 calculation for a given key and doesn't require external synchronization. Is there a reason you are hesitant to using it?

Comment: @Glide, sorry, I missed one of your questions. The `synchronized` block in your question is necessary to prevent multiple calculations for the same key, yes. Given that, if you feel you must use external synchronization, you are probably better off making the `doWork` method `synchronized` and just using a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

`CACHE.get(key)` will throw a `NullPointerException` if the key is null. Read the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Like Hashtable but unlike HashMap, this class does not allow null to be used as a key or value.

Furthermore it doesn't really make sense to synchronize over your map and try to retrieve the value again. The method should rather return that it cannot get a value for that key and that's it!

Also, no need to synchronize over a `ConcurrentHashMap` hence the name.

Create an additional method which retrieves the value from the database if the value is not in the map!

I strongly suggest to test your methods with unit tests!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with custom cache-es. Sometimes they only make things worse. I.e. they are a great source of reference leak, e.g. when the last reference to the object comes from the cache. `WeakReference`-s or [`PhantomReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html)-s can solve this problem. Check [this post](http://www.kdgregory.com/?page=java.refobj) for further details.

Another issue is the synchronization hit that comes from the `ConcurrentHashMap`. Sometimes it's worth the cost, sometimes not.

You might want to limit the cache size and remove the least used references - but that will cause some overhead too.

So, you'll have to measure performance carefully.